# How to make tableview with curved sides from left and right side

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview, swift4

I want to add a tableview which will slightly behave like a picker view. I need to add curves in left side and right side of the tableView. I am attaching a screenshot of what i have needed. Please guys help me for the same. Here is the attachment

[image]

Please give me some suggestions to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve exactly what you want easily using a table view.
I would instead, suggest looking at a custom GitHub UIPicker project that allows you to easily customise the attributes the way you want it.

Take a look at

https://github.com/filipealva/PickerView

You can add images, overlays, colours to all aspects of the picker easily and should be able to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but i want to know, is there any way possible to achieve this not exectly but approx same?